# Different rpm but same speed?

Tags: hard-drive

I have tested 3 hdd with different rpm (15k SAS, 7.2k SAS, 7.2k SATA). I transfered 1024 of 1mb files and 1gb file for a speed test (15k SAS-> 7.2k SAS, 7.2k SAS -> 7.2k SATA and vice versa). But despite the different rpm speed, file transferring speed was same. Why might be the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Are the drives rated for different transfer speeds (specifically, as opposed to rotational speed)?

Comment: A disk drive RPM is not a linear function of its speed. Under same conditions, it definitely has a correlation, but a modern 5.400rpm SATA drive will perfrom much faster in sequential read/write than an old 15K rpm SCSI disk, in part due to data density (the head passes over many more bytes on a single turn). Apart from that, a proper test should be performed from/to a device faster than all the drives you are testing, like a decent SSD or from RAM, or you will measure the performance of the bottlenecking one only.

Comment: bertieb - no transfer rate is 6gb for all the disk, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

How did you measure the speed? And why do you think there is a problem? If you transfer a file from 15k SAS-> 7.2k SAS, it will be as fast as the 7.2k SAS disk. When you transfer the fraom 7.2k SAS to 15k SAS, it will still be as fast as the 7.2k SAS disk.
When you transfer from a 7.2k SAS to 7.2 SATA, it will still be as fast as 7.2k SAS (or SATA disk).

But more importantly, RPM speed will improve the harddrives seek-time, meaning the time it will take to seek out the data that should be read/written. This will not affect the time to transfer a file significantly.

Comment: I tested with Dl380 G8, combined two 15k sas disk with raid 1, two 7.2k SAS with raid 1, and two 7.2k SATA with raid 1. 15k supports up to 210 iops and 7.2k sas, sata up to 100 iops. Transfer time was calculated by figuring out average time to transfer 1024mb file through each disk. If each disk supports different iops, shouldn't be faster or slower when you transfer file? I'm complete newb at hardware.. sorry